# Unity Game Hang

Tags: unity

I've created a prefab for coin. The Scenario is like that : When player collides with coin, the coin will move towards coin image(coin image is one which is displayed in header for information purpose). 
In a prefab, there is random number of coins attached under one empty gameobject. and one script is attached with each coin to move towards static coin image. I am posting the snippet of that script.

```
public bool isMove;

void Update(){
    if(isMove){
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("HeaderCoin").transform.position,Time.deltaTime*30);
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
    if (target.tag == "Player") {
        isMove = true;

        PlayerOfGame.instance.PlayCoins+=1;
        GamePlayController.instance.SetPlayCoins (PlayerOfGame.instance.PlayCoins);
        PlayerOfGame.instance.coins+=1;

        StartCoroutine (HideCoin ());
    }
}

IEnumerator HideCoin()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
    transform.gameObject.SetActive (false);
}
```

when playing game, it gets hang after sometime. I think the problem is with prefab. So what should I change to make my game more smooth.

Comment: Where does the coin "hang"? Does it fail to move at all? Or is the move interrupted somewhere in the middle? Or doesn't it end?

Comment: This is likely not related to the problem, but I wouldn't hide the coins with `transform.gameObject..SetActive(false)`, I would destroy them with `Destroy(gameObject)`. When you just deactivate them, they keep existing in an inactive state, which clutters up your scene and keeps consuming resources.

Comment: You may want to add some debug logging to see what happens prior to the hang.  More information that this is needed.  Though Philipp is right, having tons of inactive objects isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Destroy(gameobject, delay_time );
```

Instead of using a co-routine.

In this way you can obtain the same effect using less resources.